# update label inside updatepanel in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i need to be able to update the label text whenever i want without clicking on a button or something similar to that. the update happens based on server-client logic. i tried to use java script, but when i call the script from a function i wrote it doesn't work. now i'm trying to use updatepanel and no luck so far. i tried to use

```
UpdatePanel1.Update();
```

but it didn't refresh the label. the label defined inside the updatepanel:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label" AccessKey="l"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

is there a away to force it to refresh?

Comment: What kind of a javascript do you use?

Comment: i tried 
document.getElementById('Label2').innerHTML = 'New';

Comment: i also tried to add location.reload(true) but it didn't change the result

Comment: That element will unlike to have ID="Label2" after being rendered. Check the source code of the page from browser. The ID might have lots of prefixes added to it.

Comment: i checked and the id is Label2

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to update your label from javascript you can try this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateLabel(newValue) {
        $('#<%= Label3.ClientID %>').val(newValue);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Since OP didn't mention using jQuery, it's better to rewrite your code using pure javascript: `document.getElementById('#<%= Label3.ClientID %>').innerHTML = 'New';`

Comment: nZeus, i tried your script and it didn't work.
is the call for the script correct?

string s = "new";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "MyKey", "updateLabel(" + s + ");", true);

Comment: Emmm, No. Never use ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript. Just forget about it. Seems I didn't get your problem. Could you please describe your case? Why do you want to update your label and when.

Comment: i have a client and a server that communicate using wcf. in the client i have a function in the code behind that the server calls when there is an update (it uses IServiceCallback). when this function called i need to update the display of the client.
i checked and the communication works, the function is called the only problem is with the display update.

Comment: "i have a function in the code behind". How this function is called? You click some button on the page, it fires this function, and this function updates a label, right?

Comment: the server fires this function. i need to support a number of client that connect to the server in the same time and share information. if one of the clients press some button i need to inform the other clients that something changed. that is why the server fires the function that updates a label.

Comment: Hmm, you have a complicated flow. You can't update pages for multiple clients. To do this you need a javascript function (e.g. checkStatus()). This javascript function should make requests to the server each X seconds and server should say if there were made some changes after the last check.

Comment: thank you for your help. i was hoping to find a better solution then checking each x seconds.. i guess that's the only way..